# Compute the order and find primitive root

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to compute the orders of 2 and 7 (mod 73), and how to use the order to find a primitive root of 73. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you done either? (The orders must be factors of $72$.)

Comment: Something you could do is to simply compute $2, 2^2, 2^3, 2^4 \dots {\rm mod \ } 73$ until you eventually get $1$. But as Lord Shark says, you only need to consider exponents that are factors of 72.

Comment: How to check if 2^n mod 73 is 1, let say n is 18.

Comment: @Kay To give a an example, $2^8 = 256$. But $256 = 73*3 + 37$. So $2^8 = 37 {\rm \ mod \ } 73$. Does this answer your question, or would you like more clarification?

Comment: I am not sure if this is right so the order of 2 (mod 73) is 9 and 7(mod 73) is 24. Now how do I find the primitive roots using these two orders?

Answer (score 1):

A trick for you ( doing arithmetic modulo $\;73\;$):

$$2^6=-9\;,\;\;(-9)^2=8=2^3\implies \left(2^6\right)^2=2^3\implies\;\;\text{the order of two is...}$$

Try now to "play" around with the other one ( $\,7\,$)